# pip not working on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

My system is ubuntu 12.04 with python 2.7. This machine is behind a corporate firewall..

I have set up required proxies and everything works fine (internet, download.. browsing, sudo apt-get etc)

But the pip install is not working.
So for example,if i try to install celery, in pip log I see the following error:

```
/usr/bin/pip run on Thu Mar 20 15:32:15 2014
Downloading/unpacking celery
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/celery
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/celery: timed out
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/celery when looking for download links for celery
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for celery
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for celery:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/celery/
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/celery/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/celery/: timed out
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/celery/ when looking for download links for celery
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement celery
No distributions at all found for celery
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 948, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 152, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for celery
```

Comment: Did you try the `--proxy` argument?

Comment: @kwatford yepp.. I tried pip --proxy http://proxy.com.com:port install celery

Comment: Was my answer below helpful, did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

PIP doesn't support authenticated proxies. Do you have such proxy? Try disabling it if possible.

If you can't, you can try to install a proxy authentication service CNTLM.

After you install CNTLM, you can try running pip like this:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
sudo -E pip install some_package
```

Here you have a detailed example for the same thing, only with Ruby gems:
http://annelagang.blogspot.com/2012/11/installing-gems-in-ubuntu-1204-using.html